# What does it really mean by 'recycling' in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript

On MDN I found the following code snippet, with comment saying 'recycling same object':

```
// recycling same object
function withValue(value) {
  var d = withValue.d || (
    withValue.d = {
      enumerable: false,
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      value: null
    }
  );
  d.value = value;
  return d;
}
```

Could someone use plain language explain a little bit on what this piece of code really does? It's not so obvious for a beginner. Thanks.

And the source url:[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Also, instead of putting `d` on `withValue` function itself, why not putting it on the prototype of `withValue`, like:

```
var d = withValue.prototype.d || ( ...
```

What's the main considerations here?

Comment: I think all it's doing is using the `Function` object (`withValue`) to manipulate an object instead of something like `var d = {}`. I don't quite follow how that fits in with `Object.defineProperty()`, though.

Comment: I think the function is used to generate some properties to be passed in to the Object.defineProperty. If you assign a `d` property in `withValue` function, the returned value will be based of that assigned value instead.

Comment: It's using "recycling" in the normal English sense. It's reusing the same object used by the previous call, as opposed to creating a new object each time.

Comment: Also a side question, instead of assigning `d` to `withValue.d`, why not putting it into function's prototype, `withValue.prototype.d`? What is the consideration here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you invoke the function, it will create a new variable 'd' and assign it to itself. In OOP, the function `withValue` would be a like class and `d` would be like a static member.

```
console.log(withValue.d);    //undefined
var x = withValue(5);
console.log(x.value);    //5
console.log(withValue.d.value);    //5
console.log(x === withValue.d);    //true
```

The variable `x` and the variable `withValue.d` are both references to the same object:

```
withValue.d.value = 1;
console.log(x.value);    //1
```

If I were to invoke `withValue` again, it would recycle or reuse the existing static member (withValue.d) and update its value:

```
var y = withValue(8);   
console.log(withValue.d.value, y.value, x.value);    //8 8 8
console.log(x === y,  x === withValue.d, y === withValue.d);    //true true true
```

Update: If `withValue` were:

```
function withValue(value) {
  var d = {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: null
  };
  withValue.d = d;
  d.value = value;
  return d;
};
```

Then each invocation of the function would create a new object:

```
var x = withValue(1);
var y = withValue(2);
console.log(withValue.d.value, y.value, x.value);    //2 2 1
console.log(x === y,  x === withValue.d, y === withValue.d);    //false false true

y.value = 999;
console.log(withValue.d.value, y.value, x.value);    //999 999 1
```

So now 2 objects are created - one referenced by `y` and `withValue.d` and the other by `x`. In the first case those three variables were accessing the same object.

Comment: Hi indGov, I'm trying to follow your reasoning but still struggling with the last section: if the function `withValue` just update its value in each iteration, then what does it recycle? From your example, updating `1` to `8`, I don't see anything being recycled. Am I missing some important point? Thx.

Comment: Check the update... I've modified the function so that it doesn't recycle the object.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you imagine how useful it is in the context of Object.defineproperty(), as shown in the MDN's web page? What's the point of 'recycling' here?

Comment: Doesn't look like there's any relevance in that example. They're basically reusing the same object to supply configs to different object.

Comment: thanks, by the way could you please take a look at my edited question?

Comment: Adding it to the prototype does not make much of a difference in this case unless we are trying to inherit the `d` variable in a `new withValue()` object (which we are not doing).

Answer (score 0):

It's given as a a helper function to define the property descriptor object used as the third argument of `Object.defineProperty()` tool.

In it's first run it assigns a default private property to the `withValue` function which forces `Object.defineProperty()` to add an immutable property which is not enumerable, not writable not configurable and with the value as passed to the `withValue` function.

So the following code;

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "newProp", withValue(10));
console.log(obj); // <- Object {newProp: 10}
```

will assign `obj` a property named `newProp` that is not enumerable, not writable not configurable and with the value 10.